# Age of Ticket in asp

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm building a complaint management system in ASP.Net, and I'm working on showing the age of a ticket. I already set a `DateTimeOfTicket` column in the database when a ticket is opened, so I should be able to use the current time to calculate the age of a ticket. I am using `DateTime.Now` function. However, when I change the system datetime it shows the wrong value for the age of ticket ticket.

Code:

```
DateTime serverTime = DateTime.Now; 
DateTime utcTime = serverTime.ToUniversalTime(); 
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pakistan Standard Time"); 
DateTime localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, tzi);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the `DateTimeOfTicket` in UTC time instead of local time, and then use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now` for the comparison to get the age.

```
DateTime ticketTime = ... ; //make sure this is stored as UTC.
DateTime serverTime = DateTime.UtcNow; 
TimeSpan age = serverTime - ticketTime;
```

Comment: thanks but tell me one thing can i use datetime.now from any website like "Google"? TimeSpan age = serverTime (current time from google of any location)  - ticketTime;